# Web Page layout scrambled during loading

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

I have a page has a table contains at least 100 rows. The problem is that when the page is postback, the page layout is being scrambled during the loading and the controls positions are changed. After loading is completed, the layout turns back to normal. This problem obviously appears when connection speed is low.

Below I share 3 images. The first one is a layout look during page loading. the second is after loading completed. and the last one shows my table structure in dom. (Sorry about erasing texts in the images. Its because of confidential information.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because the page is taking long time to get loaded completely. One possible solution to avoid the problem is to hide the table initially and display it once entire page is loaded. It will avoid the scrambling problem (thought it has some disadvantages ).

initally use `<table id = "my_table" style = "display:none">`

Javascript

```
$(document).load(function(){
$("#my_table").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: thnx for ur answer mate,
the application was used to be web form and I was showing that page as a web control in the application. I didnt have that problem with it. coz the table was loaded at once. now I ve changed the structure, make it single page application. this problem appears